# reactnative - flatlist - use scrollbar to scroll

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I work on react native (react 16.2.0 , react native 0.54)

I display a large list of items with flatlist . We can take the example of a contact list with 1000 employees.

The flatlist is working good, no bug, but i cannot press the cursor of the scrollbar to navigate as in native Android or in html page.

**Steps to Reproduce**

```
 <FlatList
  ref="listRef"
  data={this.state.data}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name.toString()}
  removeClippedSubviews={true}
  extraData={{ refreshListIteration: this.state.refreshListIteration }}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderListItem(item, index)}
  initialNumToRender={15}
  ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
  ListHeaderComponent={this.renderOptionBar}
  ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
  onEndThreshold={5}
/>
```

**Expected Behavior**

So i have 1000 items in `this.state.data` that i need to display.

I initaly display 15 items (`initialNumToRender={15}`) for faster performance, so if i want to see the 600th item i need to scroll down like 40 times, not very user friendly.
I cannot press the cursor of the scrollbar like an html page to navigate very fast to the end of the list.

**Question**

Did you have any idea how to fix this or to navigate fastly without scrolling down dozen times ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a typical behaviour on iOS. The scroll indicator is usually not tappable.

FlatList has a prop called *initialScrollIndex* that you could use if you want the list to load at a particular item.
Alternatively, if you don't want to do it on start. FlatList also has the methods *scrollToIndex* and *scrollToItem* which allow you to programatically move to a specific index or item. 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

Comment: thanks for responce. i want to have a tappable scroll indicator to avoid scrolling very much times. i cannot use scrollToIndex and scrollToItem because i don't know what user want to see in this list :w